# Google Hangouts not working in Firefox on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: firefox, google, google-hangouts

[image: Google Hangouts not working]

I was wondering why Google Hangouts doesn't work in Firefox.

I don't want to download another web browser but I'm looking to get Google Hangouts working.

Any help with this appreciated!

Comment: What firefox version are you using because firefox is relecing Firefox quantum on the 14 of November witch might have a fix to this issue https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/quantum/ you can also download the beta version if you want to test it and see.

Comment: I'm currently using Firefox 56.0 (64-bit). What version is quantum? I'll look out for an update on the 14th!

Comment: It is Firefox version 57 and above but there are quite a few major changes to the browser

Comment: Google Hangouts might work with Firefox 57. I'll wait for the update and report back! Thank you Dam30n